# Invalid allocation size. Trying to merge Array Sorted List

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I have to develop two functions. One is an application level function that merges two sortedlists implemented using dynamic arrays. The other is the same except its supposed to be a member function. I get invalid allocation size. When I trace the function it successfully returns without an error buy as soon as I reach the original calling code I get the error. Here is the code for both functions.

Application level function:

```
ArraySortedType&  merge(const ArraySortedType& list1, const ArraySortedType& list2)
{
    ItemType temp;
    ArraySortedType ret, list1Copy=list1, list2Copy=list2;
    list1Copy.ResetList();
    while (list1Copy.GetNextItem(temp) == Success)
        ret.InsertItem(temp);
    list2Copy.ResetList();
    while (list2Copy.GetNextItem(temp) == Success)
        ret.InsertItem(temp);
    return ret;
}
```

Member function:

```
ArraySortedType& ArraySortedType::merge(const ArraySortedType& list)
{
    ArraySortedType s, copy = list;
    ItemType temp;
    copy.ResetList();
    while (copy.GetNextItem(temp) == Success)
        s.InsertItem(temp);
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
        s.InsertItem(info[k]);
    return s;
}
```

Code where I call functions:

```
ArraySortedType u = merge(s, n);
//ArraySortedType k = merge(s, n);
cout << "Length of u is: " << u.LengthIs() << endl;
// cout << "Length of k is: " << k.LengthIs() << endl;
```

Even the commented out code doesn't work.

Also there is alot of code for implementing the ArraySortedType that I've left out because I think it's unnecessary. Most of it was already given with the lab. InsertItem was implemented by me and is used quite a bit so I'll include it here:

```
Error_Code ArraySortedType::InsertItem ( ItemType item)
{
    if(!length)
    {
        info[0] = item;
        length++;
        return Success;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        if(info[i].ComparedTo(item) != LESS || i==length)
        {
            for(int j=length;j>i;j--)
                info[j] = info[j-1];
            info[i]=item;
            length++;
            return Success;
        }
    }
    return Fail;
}
```

GetNextItem() and ResetList() were already given so they cant be the problem so I'll leave them out but just tell me if they are required.

I've traced both of them and googled quite a bit but this problem has left me scratching my head. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I guess the implementation of ArraySortedList will be necessary. Here it is. Guess I don't really expect anyone to actually go through it though:

```
//ArraySortedType.cpp
#include "ArraySortedType.h"

ArraySortedType::ArraySortedType (int max_items) 
{
    length =0; 
    MAX_ITEMS = max_items;
    currentPos =-1;
    try
    {
        info = new ItemType[MAX_ITEMS];
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
    {
        //Severe problem, do not keep program running
        cout <<"Memory full "<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
ArraySortedType::~ArraySortedType()
{

    delete [] info;
    info = NULL;
}

void ArraySortedType::ResetList ( )
{
    currentPos = -1;
}

bool ArraySortedType::IsFull ( )  const 
{
    if(length == MAX_ITEMS)
    {  
        try
        {//Check if memory allocation is fine
            ItemType * temp = new ItemType[2*MAX_ITEMS];
            delete [] temp;
            return false;
        }
        catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool ArraySortedType::IsEmpty ()  const {
    return (length==0);
}

int ArraySortedType:: LengthIs ()  const {
    return length;
}


Error_Code  ArraySortedType::DeleteItem ( ItemType  item ) {

    int location = 0;
    while ((item.ComparedTo(info[location]) !=  EQUAL ) && location < length)
        location++;
    if (location == length) return Fail;

    info[location] = info[length - 1];
    length--;
    return Success;
}

Error_Code ArraySortedType::GetNextItem (ItemType&  item) {    
    currentPos++;
    if( currentPos == length ) return Fail;
    item = info[currentPos] ;
    return Success;
}
ArraySortedType::ArraySortedType(const ArraySortedType & ust)
{

    MAX_ITEMS =ust.MAX_ITEMS;
    length=ust.length;
    try
    {
        info = new ItemType[MAX_ITEMS];
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
    {
        //Severe problem, do not keep program running
        cout <<"Memory full "<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length; i++)
        info[i] = ust.info[i];
        currentPos=ust.currentPos;

}
ArraySortedType& ArraySortedType::operator=(const ArraySortedType & ust)
{
    if(this == &ust) return *this;

    if(MAX_ITEMS !=ust.MAX_ITEMS)
    {
        delete [] info;
        MAX_ITEMS = ust.MAX_ITEMS;
        try
        {
            info = new ItemType[MAX_ITEMS];
        }
        catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
        {
            //Severe problem, do not keep program running
            cout <<"Memory full "<< endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    currentPos=ust.currentPos;
    length=ust.length;
    for(int i=0;i<length; i++)
        info[i] = ust.info[i];

    return *this;
}

//Assumes that an employee has unique ID
bool ArraySortedType::operator==(const ArraySortedType & ust)
{
    if(this == &ust) return true;
    if(length!=ust.length) return false;
    if(currentPos!=ust.currentPos) return false;
    for(int i=0;i<length; i++)
        if(info[i].ComparedTo(ust.info[i])!=EQUAL) return false;
    return true;

}

Error_Code ArraySortedType::InsertItem ( ItemType item)
{
    if(!length)
    {
        info[0] = item;
        length++;
        return Success;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        if(info[i].ComparedTo(item) != LESS || i==length)
        {
            for(int j=length;j>i;j--)
                info[j] = info[j-1];
            info[i]=item;
            length++;
            return Success;
        }
    }
    return Fail;
}

Error_Code ArraySortedType::RetrieveItem (ItemType& item , bool& found)
{
    found = false;
    int front = 0, back = length - 1, midpoint=(length-1)/2;
    while (front<=back)
    {
        switch (info[midpoint].ComparedTo(item))
        {
        case EQUAL:
            item = info[midpoint];
            found = true;
            break;
        case LESS:
            front = midpoint + 1;
            break;
        case GREATER:
            back = midpoint - 1;
            break;
        }
        if (found)
            break;
        midpoint = ((back - front) / 2 + front);
    }
    return Fail;
}

Error_Code ArraySortedType::Delete(ItemType startKey, ItemType endKey)
{
    bool startFound = false, endFound = false;
    int numberDeleted=0, startLocation;
    bool deleting = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (info[i].ComparedTo(startKey) == EQUAL)
        {
            startLocation = i;
            deleting = true;
            startFound = true;
        }
        if (deleting)
            numberDeleted++;
        if (info[i].ComparedTo(endKey) == EQUAL)
        {
            deleting = false;
            endFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (!(startFound || endFound))
        return Fail;
    length -= numberDeleted;
    for (int i = startLocation; i < length; i++)
        info[i] = info[i + startLocation];
    return Success;
}

ArraySortedType ArraySortedType::RetrieveItemsInRange(ItemType startKey, ItemType endKey)
{
    ArraySortedType r;
    bool startFound = false, endFound = false;
    int numberDeleted = 0, startLocation;
    bool retrieving = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (info[i].ComparedTo(startKey) == EQUAL)
        {
            startLocation = i;
            retrieving = true;
            startFound = true;
        }
        if (retrieving)
            r.InsertItem(info[i]);
        if (info[i].ComparedTo(endKey) == EQUAL)
        {
            retrieving = false;
            endFound = true;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

ArraySortedType& ArraySortedType::merge(const ArraySortedType& list)
{
    ArraySortedType s, copy = list;
    ItemType temp;
    copy.ResetList();
    while (copy.GetNextItem(temp) == Success)
        s.InsertItem(temp);
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
        s.InsertItem(info[k]);
    return s;
}
```

ItemType is defined as a class Employee. I really hope I don't have to include it here as well. The class Employee has a compareTo class defined as follows:

```
RelationType Employee::ComparedTo(const Employee & e)
{
    if(eid < e.eid) return LESS;
    else if(eid == e.eid) return EQUAL;
    else return GREATER;
}
```

There is a an enum called relation type that has values LESS, EQUAL and GREATER.

Comment: Exactly where are you getting the "invalid allocation size" error? Usually you see this when you try to use `new` with an invalid size but there is no memory allocation in the question. What is `ItemType` and how is `info[]` defined to ensure you don't overflow it?

Comment: I suspect a [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) violation *somewhere*, but without seeing how `ArraySortedType` is implemented, that would be a wag-at-best.

Comment: I've edited the question to include necessary information but I'm afraid its too much.

Comment: If it is anyhow possible replace `ArraySortedType` by `std::set`. Or re-write the implementation of `ArraySortedType` to be based on `std::set`. From what you have shown of the code here the current implementation is error-prone (`new` and `insert` without growing of the array) and inefficient (linear search).

Comment: @Tobias It's a lab report so I don't think I can do that.

What do you mean by "new and insert without growing of the array"? Whenever I use insertitem() I increment length and I hardly use the new keyword in the functions that I wrote.

Also I used binary search in retrieveItem(). Should I have also used it in insertItem()?

Comment: You're *definitely* not adhering to the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) as i suspected before, but am now certain of given the posted code. You have multiple locations where you either copy-by-assignment or copy-construct your objects. Neither (copy-ctor nor assignment-op) have custom overrides to deep-copy your lists. The result is a default shallow member cop, at which time you have multiple objects referring to the same actual memory. Destruct one, the other has a dangling pointer and utilizing it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: ...and I strongly suggest as Tobias does: use `std::set<>` and iterators for this. Unless the purpose of this code is a proficiency assignment in dynamic allocation in a C++ programming class, there is little sense not to use `std::set<>`. You get dynamic growth management and sorting provided for you, and will *radically* reduce your code complexity by exploiting the wheel already invented for you. That you can use the [**set algorithms**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) from the standard library are pure bonus in reducing your code complexity even further.